# Stanford CoreNLP cannot find right version of ejml when deployed in jetty app

Tags: java, scala, stanford-nlp

There are many questions similar to this, where people get an error like the following when they are using the SentimentAnalysis library in StanfordNLP:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.ejml.simple.SimpleBase; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7560584869544985034, local class serialVersionUID = -5535333403571293496
at edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentModel.loadSerialized(SentimentModel.java:629)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.SentimentAnnotator.<init>(SentimentAnnotator.java:54)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.sentiment(AnnotatorImplementations.java:241)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$16.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:571)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:85)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:375)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:139)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:135)
at com.ccri.crusher.slotfiller.SentimentAnalyzer$.<init>(SentimentSayer.scala:31)
at com.ccri.crusher.slotfiller.SentimentAnalyzer$.<clinit>(SentimentSayer.scala)
```

And then people tell them to add this ejml (a matrix library from google) to their class path: [scala error acessing stanford corenlp sentiment - local class incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772545/scala-error-acessing-stanford-corenlp-sentiment-local-class-incompatible)

Here's another similar question:
[Getting the error while integrating stanford sentiment analysis with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492268/getting-the-error-while-integrating-stanford-sentiment-analysis-with-java)

It's even answered on in the github issues: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/8

But I don't get that error message when I compile, nor do I get it when I open a mvn:scala console. It works brilliantly then.

I get the error after launching a mvn: jetty web server, and accessing the class that way.

I've tried adding the dependency in many places in my project, including the parent level pom, and the module level pom, and as a dependency to the mvn jetty plugin, all with the same result. This is the dependency I'm adding:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library/ejml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejml</artifactId>
    <version>0.23</version>
</dependency>
```

Which is the same version that my version of Stanford CoreNLP is running (either 3.6 or 3.7 (compiled from source)).

I suspect that jetty has its own version of "ejml" and it's forcing that on Stanford instead of using version 0.23 of ejml as I specify above.

I've tried multiple versions of both Stanford and ejml without success.

**Update**: After having tried so many different versions of Stanford and ejml, and seeing that the stream vs local versions don't change a bit, I'm convinced the problem is not there. Perhaps it is something about scala/java versions being different in my .war vs my .jar?

**Update2**: mvn:dependency tree for the war (when i used ejml .21):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building crusher-war 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ crusher-war ---
[INFO] com.ccri.crusher:crusher-war:war:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.ccri.commons:commons-scalatra_2.11:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scalatra:scalatra_2.11:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scalatra:scalatra-common_2.11:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.clapper:grizzled-slf4j_2.11:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scalatra.rl:rl_2.11:jar:0.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- eu.medsea.mimeutil:mime-util:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.joda:joda-convert:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.11:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.11:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.scala-lang:scalap:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scalatra:scalatra-json_2.11:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scalatra:scalatra-scalate_2.11:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.scalatra.scalate:scalate-core_2.11:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.scalatra.scalate:scalate-util_2.11:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.11:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.ccri.dragonfish:meta-web-utils:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ccri.dragonfish:sparql-utils:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-query:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-api:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ccri.commons:sparql-endpoint_2.11:jar:1.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.rya:rya.api:jar:3.2.10-ccri:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.calrissian.mango:mango-core:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-queryalgebra-model:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-queryalgebra-evaluation:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-repository-sparql:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-repository-api:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-queryparser-api:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-queryparser-sparql:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-queryresultio-sparqlxml:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-http-client:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-http-protocol:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-queryresultio-api:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6:system
[INFO] |  |  |     +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- tomcat:jasper-compiler:jar:5.5.23:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- tomcat:jasper-runtime:jar:5.5.23:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- com.jamesmurty.utils:java-xmlbuilder:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-i18n:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- org.apache.directory.api:api-asn1-api:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     \- org.apache.directory.api:api-util:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.rya:accumulo.rya:jar:3.2.10-ccri:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-ntriples:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-nquads:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.rya:rya.indexing:jar:3.2.10-ccri:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.rya:rya.sail:jar:3.2.10-ccri:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.rya:rya.provenance:jar:3.2.10-ccri:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.tinkerpop.blueprints:blueprints-core:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-json-org:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  \- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- colt:colt:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     \- concurrent:concurrent:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-runtime:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-repository-manager:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  \- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-repository-event:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-repository-http:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-repository-contextaware:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-repository-sail:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-sail-api:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-sail-federation:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-queryparser-serql:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-queryresultio-binary:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-queryresultio-sparqljson:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-queryresultio-text:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-repository-dataset:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-binary:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-n3:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-rdfjson:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-rdfxml:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-trix:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-sail-inferencer:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-sail-memory:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-sail-nativerdf:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-sail-rdbms:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |        \- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.rya:mongodb.rya:jar:3.2.10-ccri:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:jar:1.50.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.process:jar:1.50.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |        +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |        \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.rya:rya.prospector:jar:3.2.10-ccri:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.3.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-accumulo-datastore:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-filter:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.geotools:gt-transform:jar:14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-security:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-feature-all:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-feature-common:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-feature-kryo:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-feature-avro:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-feature-nio:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-z3:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.locationtech.sfcurve:sfcurve-zorder_2.11:jar:0.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     \- org.locationtech.sfcurve:sfcurve-api_2.11:jar:0.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.geotools:gt-cql:jar:14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.geotools:gt-render:jar:14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.geotools:gt-coverage:jar:14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- org.jaitools:jt-zonalstats:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- org.jaitools:jt-utils:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.affine:jt-affine:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.iterators:jt-iterators:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.utilities:jt-utilities:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.scale:jt-scale:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     |  |  \- it.geosolutions.jaiext.translate:jt-translate:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     |  \- javax.media:jai_codec:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.algebra:jt-algebra:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandmerge:jt-bandmerge:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandselect:jt-bandselect:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandcombine:jt-bandcombine:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.border:jt-border:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.buffer:jt-buffer:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.crop:jt-crop:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.lookup:jt-lookup:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.mosaic:jt-mosaic:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.nullop:jt-nullop:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.rescale:jt-rescale:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.stats:jt-stats:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.warp:jt-warp:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.zonal:jt-zonal:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.binarize:jt-binarize:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.format:jt-format:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.colorconvert:jt-colorconvert:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.errordiffusion:jt-errordiffusion:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.orderdither:jt-orderdither:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.colorindexer:jt-colorindexer:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.imagefunction:jt-imagefunction:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.piecewise:jt-piecewise:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.classifier:jt-classifier:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.rlookup:jt-rlookup:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     \- it.geosolutions.jaiext.vectorbin:jt-vectorbin:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.geotools:gt-process-feature:jar:14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.geotools:gt-process:jar:14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |           \- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-trig:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-turtle:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-datatypes:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-languages:jar:2.7.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.accumulo:accumulo-core:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.32:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- jline:jline:jar:2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.accumulo:accumulo-fate:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.accumulo:accumulo-start:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.accumulo:accumulo-trace:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-vfs2:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-api:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-svnexe:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     +- org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-svn-commons:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     \- regexp:regexp:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework:jersey-test-framework-grizzly2:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework:jersey-test-framework-core:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  |  |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-grizzly2:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  |     +- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  |     |  \- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-framework:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  |     |     \- org.glassfish.gmbal:gmbal-api-only:jar:3.0.0-b023:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  |     |        \- org.glassfish.external:management-api:jar:3.0.0-b012:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  |     +- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http-server:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  |     |  \- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-rcm:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  |     +- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http-servlet:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  |     \- org.glassfish:javax.servlet:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  |  \- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.thrift:libthrift:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.jboss.netty:netty:jar:3.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-model:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-util:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.11:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.ccri.crusher:crusher-web-cqlknn:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ccri.crusher:crusher-suggest:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ccri:knn-core:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.ccri:knn-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.ccri:knn-iterators:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.ccri.commons:commons-serialization:jar:0.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.ccri.commons:commons-reflection-annotations:jar:0.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.11:jar:0.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.scalanlp:breeze-macros_2.11:jar:0.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.github.fommil.netlib:core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- net.sourceforge.f2j:arpack_combined_all:jar:0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.github.rwl:jtransforms:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.spire-math:spire_2.11:jar:0.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.spire-math:spire-macros_2.11:jar:0.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ccri.dragonfish:ccri-ontology:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ccri.dragonfish:dragonfish-accumulo-core:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ccri.dragonfish:dragonfish-geometry:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-utils:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:core:jar:0.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- net.sf.geographiclib:GeographicLib-Java:jar:1.44:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-main:jar:14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- net.java.dev.jsr-275:jsr-275:jar:1.0-beta-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-api:jar:14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-grid:jar:14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-data:jar:14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:14.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.media:jai_core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ccri.dragonfish:dragonfish-imagery:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ccri.dragonfish:dragonfish-breeze:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ccri.dragonfish:dragonfish-serialization:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm:jar:shaded:1.07:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.twitter:chill_2.11:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ccri.opencv:opencv:jar:2.4.11-free-fix:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.ccri.dragonfish:dragonfish-native:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.ccri.gdal:gdal-natives:jar:1.11.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.ccri.crusher:crusher-web-enrich:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ccri.crusher:crusher-enrich-core:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.ccri.crusher:crusher-enrich-imagechip:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.ccri.crusher:crusher-web-suggest:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.ccri.crusher:crusher-enrich-datetime:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.ccri.crusher:crusher-web-thumbnail:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.ccri.crusher:crusher-web-search:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ccri.crusher:crusher-search:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ccri.commons:commons-query-core:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:4.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.noggit:noggit:jar:0.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.ccri.commons:commons-query-parsing:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.ccri.crusher:crusher-web-slotfiller:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.ccri.crusher:crusher-slot-filler:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.ccri.commons:commons-reflection-loaders:jar:0.1.10:compile
[INFO] |     +- edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:jar:3.5.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- com.io7m.xom:xom:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- de.jollyday:jollyday:jar:0.4.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- javax.json:javax.json-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:jar:models:3.5.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:jar:0.21:compile
[INFO] \- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.7:compile
```

Comment: have you tried mvn dependency:tree to better understand? have a look at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: @pedrorijo91 yup, when i change the version of ejml, it shows up in mvn:dependency tree as being changes, both in the overall project, and in the war. unfortunately, this hasn't helped me understand the error.

Comment: what's the output? can you paste it? do you see any dependency conflict ?

Comment: @pedrorijo91 ok i put the mvn dependency tree information for the war

Comment: looks like you are importing twice the class, in `com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:core:jar:0.26` used for `com.ccri.dragonfish:dragonfish-geometry` and `com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:core:jar:0.23` used for `com.ccri.crusher:crusher-web-slotfiller`and cant see any exclusion , or using wrong versions in general

Answer (score 3):

I let myself quote the docs for [`java.io.Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a version number, called a `serialVersionUID`, which is used during deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the object that has a different `serialVersionUID` than that of the corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an `InvalidClassException`. A serializable class can declare its own `serialVersionUID` explicitly by declaring a field named `"serialVersionUID"` that must be static, final, and of type `long`:

```
ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
```

> If a serializable class **does not explicitly declare** a `serialVersionUID`, then the serialization runtime **will calculate a default `serialVersionUID` value** for that class **based on various aspects of the class**, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization Specification. However, it is **strongly recommended** that all serializable classes explicitly declare `serialVersionUID` values, since the default `serialVersionUID` computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can thus result in unexpected `InvalidClassExceptions` during deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent `serialVersionUID` value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable class must declare an explicit `serialVersionUID` value. It is also strongly advised that explicit `serialVersionUID` declarations use the private modifier where possible, since such declarations apply only to the immediately declaring class--serialVersionUID fields are not useful as inherited members. Array classes cannot declare an explicit `serialVersionUID`, so they always have the default computed value, but the requirement for matching `serialVersionUID` values is waived for array classes.

The problem here is that all `Serializable` classes in the `ejml` library don't have the `serialVersionUID` field. For instance [the SimpleBase class.](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml/blob/2a2bfb58d789148d06fc002e7118e5f870012683/main/simple/src/org/ejml/simple/SimpleBase.java)
So what's happening in your case is that you have data serialized by one version/build of the library but deserialized by another version/build which has different `serialVersionUID`.

That being said, you need to find out what version and build was used to serialize data and use only that build. If it was from maven, then you should use it from maven. If you compile that version on your own then there's no guarantee that `serialVersionUID` will be the same.

But the right fix would be a Pull Request to the `ejml` library that adds `serialVersionUID` value explicitly to all classes that implement `Serializable`.

Comment: So say I get a serialVersionUID into the SimpleBase class. If I understand correctly, my error is on deserialization. Wouldn't I need to also declare the same serialVersionUID in any upstream classes that serialize the object in the first place?

Comment: @compguy24 Oh, I think I wasn't clear enough. The root cause of your problem is in serialVersionUID. It's a best practice to declare serialVersionUID field if a class extends Serializable. The authors of ejml should have done it. If you use a different build(not only version) than was used for serialization, it's very possible that the serialVersionUID will be different. That's what happened.

Comment: @compguy24 Did it solve your problem? Do you still need help?

Comment: Ok, so it's solved now. Your reasoning is spot on. But actually the solution doesn't need to be on the library's end. As someone pointed out in a comment above, I have multiple versions of ejml. By excluding one in my POM, I was able to solve the problem.